# Is the dual of an equivariant metric equivariant?

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Let $g$ a finite dimensional $K$-vector space, and let $g:V \otimes V \to K$ be an inner-product. If As usual, we can use the musical isomorphisms of $g$ to define an inner product  on $V^*$, which we will denote by $g^*$. Now if we also assume that $V$ is a module for some group $G$, such that $g$ is $G$-equivariant, then with respect to the dual action of $G$ on $V^*$, does it automatically follow that $g^*$ is also $G$-equivariant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Simplest way: $g$ is $G$-invariant iff $g:V\to V^*$ is $G$-equivariant iff $g^{-1}:V^*\to V$ is $G$-equivariant iff $g^*$ (better write $g^{-1}$) is $G$-invariant.